# What’s the difference between a mild, non-physical assault, and s4 POA or Affray?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, assault, public-order, threats

(POA refers to the Public Order Act 1986.)

According to the sentencing council,

> Common assault is when a person inflicts violence on someone else or makes them think they are going to be attacked. It does not have to involve physical violence. Threatening words or a raised fist is enough for the crime to have been committed provided the victim thinks that they are about to be attacked. Spitting at someone is another example.

But then what is the purpose of having a designated offence that specifically covers causing another to fear violence, either through words (s4) or more than words (affray)?

Comment: Please spell out what "POA" is referring to at least once. This acronym has multiple legal meanings.

Comment: @ohwilleke fair enough.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful in understanding the post.